# How to count occurrences of a char in a list of words

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of words and returns a dictionary, where the keys are letters which are not vowels from any word in the list. The value is the number of occurrences of the corresponding letter.
Code so far:

```
def get_all_alphabetic_non_vowels(words_list):
    adict = {}
    vowels = "aeiou"
    
    for i in range(len(words_list)):
        words_list[i] = words_list[i].lower()
        
    for word in words_list:
        for char in word:
            if char not in vowels:
                keys = char
                occ = ''.join(words_list).count(char)
                adict[keys] = occ
    
    return adict
```

This works, however I was penalized as we weren't supposed to use .join and .count for this question to count the occurrences of the corresponding letter. I've tried implementing another nested for loop below the `keys = char` line to check for occurrences which failed so now I'm a bit confused as to where and how I should count occurences.

Comment: I think the idea is that your instructor may simply be suggesting to just check whether the current `char` is inside `adict`, if it isn't, set it to 1 (being the first occurrence of the non-vowel character), and if it is, simply increment it (e.g. `adict[char] += 1`). This way your code will only iterate through each character of each word exactly once, rather than doing an implicit iteration again (via `join` and `count`) inside each check - that's quite redundant (also explodes the computation time required).

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a job for [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You can just pass it a comprehensions that iterates and filters the letters:

```
from collections import Counter

words_list = ["hello", "world"]

counts = Counter(letter for word in words_list for letter in word if letter not in "aeiou")

#Counter({'h': 1, 'l': 3, 'w': 1, 'r': 1, 'd': 1})
```

This will give you a subclass of a dict. So this still works as expected:

```
counts['l']
# 3
```

Of course, you can do it the hard way with a dict directly:

```
words_list = ["hello", "world"]

counts = {}
for word in words_list:
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in "aeiuo":
            counts.setdefault(letter, 0)
            counts[letter] += 1
```

`setdefault(letter, 0)` initialized the dictionary entry if it's not already set. It's basically like saying `if letter not in counts: letter[counts] = 0`

The reason you were penalized is that doing `count` inside the loop is really inefficient. Each time you call `count()` python needs to iterate through the string, and you are already iterating through the string. This means that the number of iterations can explode exponentially (you are also joining the whole list into a string in the loop, which is also expensive and unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `''.join(x)` with

```py
result = ''
for char in x:
    result += char
```

and you can replace `x.count(y)` with

```py
count = 0
for char in x:
    if x == y:
        count += 1
```

The above only works if `y` is a single-character string, which in your case is. That said, you can refactor

```py
occ = ''.join(words_list).count(char)
```

as

```py
words = ''
for word in words_list:
    words += word

occ = 0
for c in words:
    occ += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = set('aeiou')
words = ['Lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']
out_dict = {}
# join, remove vowels, lower, sort and iterate
for ch in sorted(''.join(words).translate({ord(i): None for i in vowels}).lower()):
    out_dict[ch] = out_dict.setdefault(ch, 0) + 1
print(out_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'d': 1, 'l': 2, 'm': 3, 'p': 1, 'r': 2, 's': 2, 't': 2}
```